Valid covariate definitions that respect temporal relationships in regression models
I am trying to gain a better understanding of reasonable assumptions to make and valid ways to define covariates in regression models. I am putting aside survival methods where time is fundamental to the estimation (risk calculated based on covariate values present at each event time) and it is clear that covariates should either be at baseline or parameterised as time-varying covariates if their status changes after the start of observation.
However, what about non-survival models (linear/logistic/poisson/etc) that aren't strictly cross-sectional or longitudinal? – e.g. you might want to investigate the association between a ‘baseline’ set of covariates and an outcome at some point in the future, so there is a temporal relationship of sorts, but the outcome has only been measured once.
Is it reasonable in these cases to use covariates that aren’t strictly baseline but rather some time-invariant summary/average over the time period?
Is this context dependent?
For example, if you were interested in a prognostic model – i.e. the ability to predict an outcome using a current set of predictors, then you can’t really predict that outcome with information you don’t technically have at that point in time. So a time-invariant summary/average wouldn't be valid here.
But if you were instead interested in looking at the associations between the covariate and the outcome - rather than predicting the outcome, is it a reasonable use in this case?
(edit: re-reading this, I guess I'm just describing a cohort study)

You're basically asking whether it's "reasonable" to use information you have available.  Why not?

Fair enough. I am overthinking it then. Yes, you have the information after you finish the study. I guess I was just trying to get my head around whether using covariates that aren't fully baseline, nor accounted for in a time-varying manner, had implications for the extent of inference/prediction one can make.
